# Imprimir elementos de uma lista

Tags: c#, lista

Há alguma maneira de ler os valores que estão numa lista e apresentá-los na consola?

Experimentei assim, mas não dá certo

```
Console.WriteLine(lista);
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas atendem o que foi pedido? Se sim, você pode marcar uma delas como correta. Caso contrário, você pode deixar um comentário dos autores pedindo maiores esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 12):

Tem que passar por todos os itens da lista e imprimi-los.

```
foreach(var elemento in lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elemento);
}
```

Se quiser uma versão *one-liner*. Isso só funciona para `List`, nada além.

```
lista.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RhMPLH)

**Aviso**: Se a lista for de objetos, isso chamará o método `ToString()` dos objetos. Se este não for o comportamento desejado, podes imprimir propriedade por propriedade, ou até mesmo criar um método que retorne uma `string` com as propriedades que queres mostrar.

Exemplo usando as propriedades

```
foreach(var elemento in lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elemento.Propriedade);
    Console.WriteLine(elemento.OutraPropriedade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach([tipo lista] lista on [nome da lista]{

    Console.WriteLine(lista);

}
```

Onde [Tipo lista] é o tipo (string, float,double,int, object) e nome da lista é o nome que você deu, exemplo:

```
List<string> listaString = new List<String>();
Foreach(string lista on listaString {
    Console.WriteLine(lista);
}
```